# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint ... In Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, foreign-keys, relational-database, sqlexception

When I want to create or add data in database, I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.CompanyProfiles_dbo.Users_Id". The conflict occurred in database "AppDb", table "dbo.Users", column 'Id'. The statement has been terminated.

I have a one-to-one relationship between `User` and `CompanyProfile`.

**User.cs**

```
 public class User : IdentityUser<Guid, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>
 {
     ...
     // navigation properties
     public virtual CompanyProfile CompanyProfile { get; set; }
 }
```

**CompanyProfile.cs**

```
public class CompanyProfile
{
    ...
    // navigation property
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
}
```

**CompanyProfileConfig.cs**

```
public class CompanyProfileConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<CompanyProfile>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="CompanyProfileConfig"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public CompanyProfileConfig()
    {
        this.HasKey(_ => _.Id);

       ...

        this.HasRequired(_ => _.User)
            .WithOptional(_ => _.CompanyProfile);

    }
}
```

also I get this query in SQL Server Profiler:

```
INSERT[dbo].[CompanyProfiles] ([Id], [CompanyName], [Activity],[Description], 
                               [WebSite], [Phone], [UserId], [Address])
VALUES('aee90a37-425a-4a2c-a3df-2c2c95ad954c' /* @0 - [Id] */,
       'My Company' /* @1 - [CompanyName] */,
       'Programmer' /* @2 - [Activity] */,
       'MyDescription' /* @3 - [Description] */,
       'http://example.com' /* @4 - [WebSite] */,
       '66663369' /* @5 - [Phone] */,
       '2f4e0f48-b7e3-4bfb-98fe-69daa1cb501a' /* @6 - [UserId] */,
       'MyAddress' /* @7 - [Address] */)
```

My post ActionResult:

```
  public virtual async Task<ActionResult> CreateProfile(CompanyProfileViewModel viewModel)
  {
        viewModel.UserId = new Guid(_identity.GetUserId());

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _companyProfileService.Create(viewModel);
            await _uow.SaveAllChangesAsync();
        }

        return View(MVC.Company.Profile.ActionNames.CreateProfile,viewModel);
    }
```

CompanyProfile table screenshot:

[image]

Comment: can you post the code where you're trying to add it? ..cause it look like EF is tryng to add also a new user (even if it's already exist) or maybe the user you're linking doesn't exist

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi Added to ask

Comment: yeah .. this show your problem ... you can't generate a new guid for userID ... qhy are you doing so?

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi  GetUserId method return string but my userId is Guid

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi I Can't convert string to Guid so resharper offer this way for fix problem

Comment: try to post also your service or repository code

Comment: but becarfully .. User. GetUserId() retirve tha AspNEtUSer id .. i think you have another User Table .. and the userID is there

Comment: @gertarnold so I delete UserId?

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi No Have One User Table

Comment: can you post maybe also your _companyProfileService and repository?

Comment: @gertarnold Update My Ask Add Photo

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi yes just problem is save in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a 1:0..1 association here (`User:CompanyProfile`). EF implements this by using the primary key of the dependent entity (`CompanyProfile`) as foreign key to the principal entity. Thus, both records have the same PK in the database.

In your case, not being able to look into your service methods, I assume you can remove `UserId` from `CompanyProfile` and change `viewModel.UserId = new Guid(_identity.GetUserId())` into

```
viewModel.Id = new Guid(_identity.GetUserId());
```

Comment: Great Answer Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is you're generating new Guid .. so EF goes in error... what if you just try with this:

```
 public virtual async Task<ActionResult> CreateProfile(CompanyProfileViewModel viewModel)
        {
            viewModel.UserId = _identity.GetUserId();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {



  _companyProfileService.Create(viewModel);
            await _uow.SaveAllChangesAsync();
        }

        return View(MVC.Company.Profile.ActionNames.CreateProfile,viewModel);

    }
```

Or try to retrive the correct user From DB and then link it?

Comment: use Guid.parse(_identity.GetUserId()); but not fixed